# Check if a function is in H2

Tags: analysis, partial-derivative, weak-derivatives

I want to check if the Function

$u(x)=|x-1|$

is in
$H^{2}(\Omega) , \Omega = (0,2) $

My idea: I want to check if the function has a weak derivative. But that would only proof $L^{1}$ what should I do next? Checking if there is a weak derivative for the weak derivate? Then I would have at least proven $L^{2}$.  How do I proof that the set is in $H^{2}$ now?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a little confused about what all this is saying. Or at least, I'm confused reading your question. Let's unravel everything and make sure we're on the same page. $H^2(\Omega)$ is the function space $W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ consisting of all functions on $\Omega$ with all weak-partials of order $l \leq 2$ being $L^2$ functions. Since $\Omega$ is a region in $\mathbb{R}$, we just drop the word 'partial.' So it has to have two weak derivatives, and they both need to be $L^2$ functions. There's two steps then clearly, one is to calculate the weak derivatives, and the other is to observe they are in $L^2(\Omega)$.

For both steps, I see no reason why we should use $\Omega$ as you've been given it, rather than translate it so that things are at the origin, just to make the algebra easier. So let's move everything so that $f(x) = |x|$ and $\Omega = (-1,1)$. From here, I provide a sketch of the argument, leaving the details to you - there is really no good way to get a grip on Sobolev spaces other than doing some of these calculations.

I claim a weak-derivative of this function is the Heaviside step function $H(x)$. I leave the proof to you - this should be not so hard since the definition of the weak derivative is basically just integration by parts against test functions, and on each ray, the derivative is $\pm 1$, only being undefined at $0$. Is this function $L^2$? Yes. What's $|H(x)|$? Why is it clearly $L^p$?

What is the second weak derivative? Well it's a weak derivative of $H(x)$. If this function exists, again, it satisfies an integration by parts formula, by definition. But this one is a bit more problematic. One way to prove that such a function does not exist is to take a sequence of test functions, with $\varphi_1(0) = 1$, and then define $\varphi_n(x) = \varphi_1(nx)$. Then since all of these functions have their support contained in $\Omega$, and we are compressing them by a factor of $n$, they go to $0$ in the $L^2$ norm. On the other hand, if you write $\int_\Omega f(x) \varphi_n(x)$ where $f$ denotes a candidate for weak derivative, then can you evaluate this for each $n$? Take the limit, and obtain a contradiction.

Comment: So. I found the Heaviside Step as a weak derivative. What exactly did I prove with this? This isn't enough to proof $H^{2}$. Right? Trying to find a weak derivative of $H(x)$ gives me a contradiction. Thus there seem to be no 2nd derivative. 
Does that mean this function is not part of $H^{2}$?
What if there would be the second weak derivative? Would it be enough to proof $H^{2}$ or would I need to do something more?

How would I proof $L^{2}(\Omega)$? Would I need to proof convexity?

Comment: And another question. Let's say I have the function $x^2$ which has a strong derivative and a second strong derivative. Does that automatically mean that I these derivatives are also weak derivatives? And is that automatically in $H^{2}(\Omega)$?

Comment: Being H2 means having suitable weak derivatives and also that they are L2. So you have to check these things are L2.

Comment: Checking if they are L2 can be done by checking by checking if the bilinear form is coercive?

Comment: I don't know what coercive means. Checking if they are L2 to me means computing $\int_\Omega |f|^2$ and checking it's $< \infty$.